# How to setup as a scanner server with web interface

Tags: software-installation, server, tutorial

There are several tutorials online for how to setup the Pi to scan and email/dropbox with one button push. Cool, but I'd rather have a web interface so a user in my network can change scan options.

I've found two solutions [phpSANE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/) and [Sane WI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sanewi/).

Has anybody successfully set these or any other solution on their Pi? How'd you do it? Or anyone know how to? Please keep in mind, I'm a linux noob.

Also, if it matters, my Pi also functions as a print server, with CUPS.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Comment: no, have not found an answer

Comment: it seems both phpSANE and SaneWI have been abandoned (last releases in 2013 and 2003, respectively). a new option i might look at in the future is [scanserv](https://github.com/sbs20/scanserv/), another PHP app that serves a similar, if reduced, functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished installing phpSANE with nginx on a Raspberry Pi, and I can see why it may be challenging. It was only after the fact that I discovered that most of the information is available online. Here is a good tutorial on setting up nginx (being lighter than Apache, it might be a better choice for a Pi) - http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2013/Sep/setup-a-web-server-on-rpi/
(Alternative link - https://web.archive.org/web/20150925070011/http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2013/Sep/setup-a-web-server-on-rpi/)

This next is a great tutorial that will help you getting the scan server going, but with a few caveats (see below) https://extremeshok.com/6138/ultimate-raspberry-pi-lan-print-scan-and-pdf-server-cups-airprint-ipp-cups-pdf-sanescan-sanetwain-phpsane-scanner-webinterface-samba-remote-file-access/

1. *saned* is started automatically on boot, and I didn't have to deal with *xinet.d* (but you can still do this step if you'd like)
2. I didn't need to reboot after installing sane-backends to get the scanner recognized
3. Add *pi* and *www-data* to the *scanner* group (*usermod -a -G scanner www-data*)

The rest of the instructions in that tutorial are still correct at the time of this writing, although mind you, if you plan accessing anything else on that Pi via web, perhaps you'd want to set up virtual hosts, and not place everything in /var/www

Comment: In general, if you're willing to put in the legwork, Nginx works a treat on RPi, much more lightweight than Apache, from a resource utilization perspective.